# Google Script Alignment Text position

Tags: google-sheets

I want to know how I can align texts.

Right now I have:

Monday:OFF    OT:   0

Tuesday:OFF    OT:   0

Wednesday:OFF    OT:   0

Thursday:OFF    OT:   0

Friday:OFF    OT:   0

Saturday:OFF    OT:   0

Sunday:OFF    OT:   0

.
.

And I want this:

Monday:......OFF    OT:   0

Tuesday:.....OFF    OT:   0

Wednesday:OFF    OT:   0

Thursday:....OFF    OT:   0

Friday:........   OFF    OT:   0

Saturday: ...OFF    OT:   0

Sunday:  .... OFF    OT:   0

Yes I know I can use spacing to make the same but is there another way to do it?

Thanks All

Comment: Why don't you select all the columns and change the alignment? Or do you want a script to do it?

Answer (score -1):

If this is a Google Script question we need to know what data is in which cells.

If this is just a Google Sheets question you would want to split the information into three cells with the SPLIT() function dividing things up on the ':' symbol.